# How do I add a new solution to my team project?

Tags: tfs

We have a team project in TFS 2010. This team project is used as a container for a few smaller, related projects in order to share bugs, work items, etc. My question, how do I add a new VS solution to this team project?

I created the new solution in my local working folder. The team project is already created on the server. When I go into the Source Control Explorer and try to add the new solution to the project, I can’t add the new solution because I don’t have a destination folder mapped. I can’t map the destination folder because I can’t figure out how to add a new folder to the server project for the new solution. Caught in what appears to be some wicked circular logic… help!?!

Answer (score 0):

### **To add a new solution from you local files to TFS you could:**

In the solution explorer **right click** on the **solution** and select '**Add Solution to Source Control**'

Then you can right click and select **check in**.

Then the entire solution will be added to your team project in TFS.

[image]

Comment: What if I had two team project? how can I add it to a specific team project?